# what is the gain of this amplifier at resonance frequency?

Tags: gain

[image]

I want to analyze this circuit but I do not know how to compute its gain at the resonance frequency.
In lab its gain at resonance frequency (910kHz) was 54.

Comment: The question can't be answered in its present form because important details are missing. Hint: What is the output impedance of the signal source?

Comment: the output impedance of the signal source is 50 ohm

Answer (score 1):

Based simply on small-signal analysis, the voltage gain of a common-base amplifier is simply the ratio of the collector and emitter impedances. At resonance, the tank circuit has a very high impedance, so the collector impedance is equal to the load impedance: 10 kΩ. If your source impedance is 50 Ω, this should give a gain of 200.

However, let's take a closer look at the circuit overall. You're biasing the transistor with a network that has a Thevenin voltage of 4.25 V and a resistance of 2.1 kΩ. This means that there is about 3.6 V across the emitter resistor, and the quiescent current through the transistor is about 1.33 mA.

Now, a voltage source of 50 mV RMS with a series impedance of 50 Ω is equivalent to a current source of 1 mA RMS in parallel with 50 Ω. The peak current is actually ±1.414 mA, which is greater than the quiescent current of the transistor.

This means that your transistor is cutting off for some portion of each cycle, which at least partly explains the anomalous gain value you measured. This also makes it difficult to predict what the theoretical gain value should be, since the "small signal" linearization assumptions no longer apply.

Did you try measuring the gain at different source signal levels? Try it at 10 mV and 20 mV and see what results you get.

One other note: How were you measuring the output voltage across the 10 kΩ resistor? If you were using an oscilloscope, I would point out that the typical 10 pF input capacitance of a scope probe represents an impedance of just 17 kΩ at 910 kHz. In parallel with the resistor, this reduces the effective load impedance on the transistor to about 8.6 kΩ

Comment: isn't the base voltage 4.25V and emitter is about 3.6V?

Comment: @Andyaka: Ah, you're right. I misread the supply voltage as 12V.

Comment: Yeah it don't make any difference tho!!!

Comment: The 10pF input capacitance doesn't affect the load impedance. It's in parallel with C2 (1nf) , so it does affect the resonant frequency slightly.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: At resonance, the impedance of the C2-L1 tank circuit is very high -- much higher than the combination of C3 and R5, so it's the latter that primarily determine the load impedance that the transistor collector "sees". Putting 10 pF in parallel with R5 definitely has a significant effect. Sure, there might also be a 0.5% shift in the resonant frequency, but that isn't relevant to the gain calculation.